# Is there a high-res patch for Dark Reign?

Tags: dark-reign

Is there a high-resolution patch for [Dark Reign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Reign:_The_Future_of_War)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, you'll have to set your desktop resolution to 640x480 to play it like old times. The game is no longer being updated.

Comment: Hopefully a modder will make one.